# OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error when listening a TX signal from ESP8266 on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port, esp8266

so here is my Python script that i ran on the Raspberry :

```
import serial
import time

def receive_data():
data = ""

while ser.in_waiting > 0:
    data += ser.read().decode('utf-8')
data = data.strip()
return data

# Define the serial port and baud rate
port = '/dev/ttyS0'  # Use '/dev/ttyAMA0' for Raspberry Pi 3 or earlier models
baudrate = 115200

# Open the serial port
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=1)

# Main loop
while True:
   data = receive_data()
   print("Received data:", data)
   time.sleep(0.5)
```

and here is the code that i wrote to transmit the data from the ESP8266 :

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200); // Inisialisasi komunikasi serial dengan kecepatan 9600 baud
}

void loop() {
int randomData = random(0, 100); // Menghasilkan data acak antara 0 hingga 99

Serial.print("Data acak: ");
Serial.println(randomData); // Menampilkan data acak di Serial Monitor

delay(500); // Menunda selama 1 detik
}
```

it works both listening on the PC's Serial Monitor or through the Raspberry's and ESP's TX and RX port. but when listening from the raspberry by running the .py script through a terminal, i might sometimes get the following error :

```
Received data: 
Received data: Data acak: 58
Received data: 
Received data: Data acak: 62
Received data: Data acak: 69
Received data: Data acak: 70
Received data: Data acak: 6
Received data: Data acak: 56
Received data: Data acak: 83
Received data: Data acak: 44
Received data: Data acak: 78
Received data: Data acak: 46
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/leppy-chan/pindah.py", line 21, in <module>
   data = receive_data()
 File "/home/leppy-chan/pindah.py", line 7, in receive_data
   while ser.in_waiting > 0:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 531, in 
  in_waiting
    s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
     OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

i wonder what's wrong, any help would be appreciated :)